# How do I avoid this meshing of textview and buttons?

Tags: android, overlap

> Issue:

[image]

I have seen this overlap anytime I have a button under a textview or edittext. If I try to add text to one of these, the keyboard forces the buttons to raise. What causes this overlap and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for the activity you're using the layout, for example:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
```

For more info go to the following link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode

Comment: Is this in the overall layout or...?

Comment: Edited my answer, add it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

Change `RelativeLayout` to other type of layout or specify different `android:windowSoftInputMode` in your manifest for this activity.